# Unable to load csv file into Dataframe using Surprise in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, dataframe

### The Scenario

The Dataset is to be imported which consists has considerable `NaN` values in it. For same I'm using SurPRISE package (written by Nicholas Hug) in Python rather than using Pandas. Reason being the Method of predicting NaN values is good with mentioned package.

### The Problem

Dataset **post_df1.csv** is as mentioned below:

```
       uid     iid       rat
1    303.0   785.0  3.000000
2    291.0  1042.0  4.000000
3    234.0  1184.0  2.000000
4    102.0   768.0  2.000000
5    181.0  1081.0  1.000000
...
194  944.0  110.0       NaN
195  944.0  111.0       NaN
196  944.0  112.0       NaN
197  944.0  113.0       NaN
198  944.0  114.0  5.000000
199  944.0  115.0  5.000000
```

Importing it using SurPRISE

```
reader = Reader(line_format="user item rating", sep='\t', rating_scale=(1, 5))
df = Dataset.load_from_file('post_df1.csv', reader=reader)
```

returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/surprise/dataset.py", line 173, in load_from_file
    return DatasetAutoFolds(ratings_file=file_path, reader=reader)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/surprise/dataset.py", line 306, in __init__
    self.raw_ratings = self.read_ratings(self.ratings_file)
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/surprise/dataset.py", line 205, in read_ratings
    itertools.islice(f, self.reader.skip_lines, None)]
  File "/home/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/surprise/dataset.py", line 455, in parse_line
    return uid, iid, float(r) + self.offset, timestamp
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I'm unable to figure out, where's the String! since **post_df1.csv** when read using Pandas, returns this:

```
post_df1.dtypes

uid    float64
iid    float64
rat    float64
dtype: object
```

### Questions

1. What is the possibility that when reading it using this package might treat entire data as string?
2. I noticed in Error, that float has an offset and timestamp as return value in Dataset.py. How can I limit it upto *uid, iid, rat / float* only?

> return uid, iid, float(r) + self.offset, timestamp
>    3. List item

### References

[Suprise Package Docs](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

### EDIT #1

So, here's how the **post_df1** & **post_df2** are formed. Also for **post_df1** I tried to take values from row 1 onwards, in case 0th row is header.

```
# PRE PROCESSED CLUSTER 0 -- Named to POST DataFrame1
if flag1 is 1:
    print pre_df01
    post_df1 = pre_df01.iloc[1:, :]
elif flag1 is 2:
    print pre_df02
    post_df1 = pre_df02.iloc[1:, :]
elif flag1 is 3:
    print pre_df03
    post_df1 = pre_df03.iloc[1:, :]

# PRE PROCESSED CLUSTER 1 -- Named to POST DataFrame2
if flag2 is 1:
    print pre_df11
    post_df2 = pre_df11
elif flag2 is 2:
    print pre_df12
    post_df2 = pre_df12
elif flag2 is 3:
    print pre_df13
    post_df2 = pre_df13
```

Here, I've already tried removing header and index to avoid any string type in it.

```
# EXPORT TO CSV & LOAD AGAIN IN PROGRAM
post_df1.to_csv("post_df1.csv", sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
post_df2.to_csv("post_df2.csv", sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Since, importing is issue in code, I looked into csv file using Spreadsheet, here's how it looks
[image: post_df1.csv in LibreOffice Calc]
Clearly it is without Headers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this error arise because of header of each column in post_df1.csv, which is in string format. When you remove first row with column names from csv file, your snippet of code should be working.

Comment: Turns out I did predict that, and tried `post_df1 = pre_df02.iloc[1:, :]` but doesn't help. Any Ideas on how can I go for `header = False` with `pre_def02.iloc[1:, :]` which is a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: you can save post_df1 DataFrame with method .to_csv('post_df1.csv', index=False, header=None). In result, you'l have csv file with float numbers without header. After that you can do your snippet of code. In your case, from past comment, you save post_df1 without first line, but with header.

Comment: And you should specify separator to '\t'. After that it should be like this pre_df02.to_csv('post_df1.csv', index=False, header=None, sep='\t'). And you shouldn't assign result to variable.

Comment: Any more ideas Ed? If not, I'd like to have better option over this.

Comment: Is this line work now? df = Dataset.load_from_file('post_df1.csv', reader=reader). And remove rating_scale=(1, 5) from arguments, it's redundant in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155926/discussion-between-t3j45-and-eduard-ilyasov).